# Use firebase to access google cloud datastores data

Tags: firebase, laravel-5, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, laravel-5.4

I want to connect my laravel app with google cloud datastore and want to use same data for android and ios application, for that i want to use firebase.

Can any one have idea that how can i access my google cloud datastore's data in firebase ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using Cloud Functions for Firebase to fetch/query data for you using the Node.js client libraries.

Documentation:

- [Google Cloud Node SDK](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node#cloud-datastore-ga) for Cloud Datastore
- [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) for Firebase

Comment: Thanks i will try. and if stuck anywhere then reopen this question.

Comment: example https://medium.com/@chriswrite/cloud-function-and-datastore-tutorial-intro-to-build-a-server-less-service-92bc106ef8e5

Answer (score 0):

You could also try Cloud Functions for Firebase and/or Firestore DB instead of Google Cloud Datastore.

Firestore is the next evolution of Firebase (Realtime DB) with better support for scaling & data modeling + offline data management.